# URL encode Text with line breaks in java

Tags: java, httprequest, urlencode

So I have an `ArrayList` of `String` objects that I want to send in a Http POST request using the Apache Http Client.

What I am doing now is concatenating the List objects to a new `String` each followed by a `System.getProperty("line.separator")` for a linebreak. 
However I get a bad response from the server, telling my the URL is malformed.
Thanks in advance for your help!

```
ArrayList<String> episodeList
String episodesAsString = "";

    for(String s : episodeList)     
            episodesAsString = episodesAsString.concat(s + NL);

        URI uri = new URI(
                "https", 
                "my.domain.com", 
                "/path/add?this=123456&application=myApp&event=myEvent&description=" + episodesAsString,
                null);


    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

Comment: If this is a POST request, why are you sending the payload in the URL and not as POST data? Does the other end require that?

Comment: Now that's a good question. Sorry, I will fix that asap!

Comment: Try to send your payload as a request body for POST and maybe try PostMethod post = new PostMethod(url);
  post.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", contentType);

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are not sending `POST` data. The problem might be with bad URL.

Try this:

```
String strUrl = "http://localhost:7001/RESTFUL_Tutorial/rest/hello/test1/test naveen kumar/test pwd";

URL url = new URL(strUrl);
// for getting URI
URI urlinfo = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
// for getting URL
url = urlinfo.toURL();
```

For more better use [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String%29)

place your url.. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems by `NL` you mean new line character. Instead after concatinating all the strings and using `\n` instead of NL, use [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String%29) to encode the string. Also check if the URL is being passed badly in debug.

Answer (score 0):

I think the URI is the problem.  Even though I think you can construct a proper URL using it, you are missing the '//' before the hostname.  I your example, I believe the request would be going to:

```
https:my.domain.com/path/addthis=123456&application=myApp&event=myEvent&description=XXX
```

This is based on the 5min I just spent reading the JavaDoc of the URI class.  You could probably test this by putting a Proxy or sniffer on and seeing what the payload of the headers look like.